# Bootstrap not loading in chrome

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Angular and working on a test project, in which I am using Bootstrap version 3. The Bootstrap navbar, row, col and other features are not rendering in Chrome.

I checked the DOM structure in dev tools, and it shows Bootstrap integrated within a style tag.

Code from one of the components:

[image: Code from one of the components]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you provide your code in a snippet rather than an image.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not inlcuded bootstrap in your angular.json.

In your angular.json add the below code

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Comment: thank you for the response but I have done this already. Please let me know if you need any other info, in which I might have did something wrong. 

"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],